# Media server died when start recording video

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer

I've searched around lot but no answer for my problem.
I got the Media server died after call `MediaRecorder.start();`

The error I got is:

> CameraSource﹕ frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/CameraSource.cpp:808 timestampUs > mLastFrameTimestampUs
> libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)
> ...
> IMediaDeathNotifier﹕ media server died
>
> Camera﹕ binderDied
>
> Camera﹕ Camera server died!
>
> Camera﹕ ICamera died

I don't know what the reason is. Can anyone please help me...

Comment: share some source code, this way nobody can help you

Comment: i follow extractly this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video

Comment: This error occurs when i stop/start camera preview. I have to stopPreview beacause i need to confirm if the user want to save or not the recorded video. It doesn't occur every time but usually